# ASP.NET Routing - Adding a route only if numeric?

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I am trying to generate a route using ASP.NET routing, but I only want it to apply if certain values are numeric.

```
        // Routing for Archive Pages
        routes.Add("Category1Archive", new Route("{CategoryOne}/{Year}/{Month}", new CategoryAndPostHandler()));
        routes.Add("Category2Archive", new Route("{CategoryOne}/{CategoryTwo}/{Year}/{Month}", new CategoryAndPostHandler()));
```

Is there anyway to know if {Year} and {Month} are numeric values. Otherwise this routing conflicts with other routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to Richard and Martin for pointing me in the right direction. The syntax I ended up needing is:

```
routes.Add("Category1Archive", new Route("{CategoryOne}/{Year}/{Month}/", new CategoryAndPostHandler()) { Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { Year = @"^\d+$", Month = @"^\d+$" }) });
routes.Add("Category2Archive", new Route("{CategoryOne}/{CategoryTwo}/{Year}/{Month}/", new CategoryAndPostHandler()) { Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { Year = @"^\d+$", Month = @"^\d+$" }) });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the filter you want using [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.constraints.aspx):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Category1Archive",
    new Route("{CategoryOne}/{Year}/{Month}",
            null,
            new {Year = @"^\d+$", Month = @"^\d+$"},
            new CategoryAndPostHandler()
    )
 );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Category2Archive",
    new Route("{CategoryOne}/{CategoryTwo}/{Year}/{Month}",
            null,
            new {Year = @"^\d+$", Month = @"^\d+$"},
            new CategoryAndPostHandler()
    )
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Richard is right, but I wanted to add:

[13 Asp.Net MVC Extensibility Points](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/08/13-asp.net-mvc-extensibility-points-you-have-to-know.aspx)

[IRouteConstraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint.aspx)